# OpenVpn3 cannot install

Tags: apt, dependencies, openvpn

I get this error message when trying to install openvpn3 in Ubuntu 22.04.

[image]

Comment: Where does the package come from, a PPA or something? It's not in the default repos. Please don't leave out vital information.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to ensure that you have the 'universe' repo and the security repos added to your sources to obtain these packages.